# Final runtime of $O(k \log k \log n)$

Tags: logarithms

What would this resolve to?

$O(k \log k \log n)$

The logs are the same base here and for the life of me right now I can't remember how to multiply logarithms together....

Basically what is $\log k * \log n$?

Comment: Why would you like to modify the expression ?

Comment: I have an algorithm that gives a runtime of $O(k \log k \log n)$. And I just want to know if I can simplify $k \log k \log n$ any further...

Comment: Maybe you confused with $\log(kn)= \log k + \log n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you know something about how $k$ relates to $n$ directly, there's probably not much more that can be done. You may be thinking of $\log(nk) = \log(n) + \log(k)$, but that's a different log rule.

In terms of big-O notation, it's clear as-is, unless there's some specific reason you wish to change it. For example you could also state it as $O(k \log(n^{\log(k)}))$ or $O(k \log(k^{\log(n)}))$, but these representations may be less clear.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking of. So I was right and there is nothing more I can do. Thanks!